# Video Site Example

Tags: video

Microsoft have a tutorial on creating a Video Site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464364.aspx

Does anyone have an example about the result for this? The tutorail looks like it will take a while to implement and I don't know if it will be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there was a 2007 solution called the Podcasting Kit for SharePoint that was available on Codeplex, http://pks.codeplex.com. It looks to be abandoned.  I thought I had heard they were going to be coming up with a 2010 solution on the product.  That being said, here's a link to a youtube video that has a few snips of information on Microsoft's implementation, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-D3g1A5ocik.